# Google Kubernetes Engine Node Upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm seeing this notification "Node version unsupported" at my Kubernetes Cluster
My Current Kubernetes version of nodes is 1.7.8-gke.0 and Master version     is 1.7.12-gke.1
Do I have to upgrade it immediately ? or how long do I have to wait until I do an upgrade ?
I thought Kubernetes Engine does not ONLY support running node versions more than two minor versions behind the master version !!
[image]

Comment: It just literally means that the node version is no longer under support. It does not mean it's not compatible with the master. (If it wasn't compatible then the cluster wouldn't work.) You don't have to upgrade right away. It's like any other software- if your cluster is carrying production workloads and you have a strange problem with a node, the vendor will say- upgrade your node and then we'll look at it. But it should continue to work. GKE will probably stop running 1.7 masters soon after 1.10 comes out in a few weeks, but 1.7 nodes should still work with 1.8 and 1.9 masters.

Comment: @JonahB - that is a great answer -- I'm curious why you left it as a comment rather than answering the question.

Comment: thank you for the information..I'm planning to do an upgrade anyway, but just wanted to know if it has to been done immediately. again I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy-paste my comment above:

It just literally means that the node version is no longer under support. It does not mean it's not compatible with the master. (If it wasn't compatible then the cluster wouldn't work.) You don't have to upgrade right away. It's like any other software- if your cluster is carrying production workloads and you have a strange problem with a node, the vendor will say- upgrade your node and then we'll look at it. But it should continue to work. GKE will probably stop running 1.7 masters soon after 1.10 comes out in a few weeks, but 1.7 nodes should still work with 1.8 and 1.9 masters